# Cant get id in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

Main Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1,b2;
DBHelper mydb;
TextView id;
ListView listView;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
String[] from = new String[] { mydb.ID,
        mydb.NAME, mydb.ADDRESS };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);





    Cursor cursor = mydb.fetch();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, cursor, from, to, 0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);




    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            id=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
            int id_To_Search = Integer.valueOf(id.getText().toString());

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("_id", id_To_Search);

          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddPatient.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Add class

```
  if (extras != null) {
        b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int Value = extras.getInt("_id");

        if (Value > 0) {

            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
            rs.moveToFirst();



            name.setText(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME)));
            address.setText(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS)));
            mobile.setText(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE)));
            if(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.GENDER)) != "female")
            {
                male.setChecked(true);
            }
            else
            {
                female.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

                }
```

DBHelper

```
 public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select * from patients where _id=" + id + "", null);
}
```

Main.xml

```
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp" />
```

list.xml

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/id"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

How can i get the id of the clicked list and show those details for edit in the next page.?How can i do it. Please help me. The next page is used to edit and delete purposes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the view to find view id for list elements.
Change below line in onItemClick()

```
 id=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
```

to

```
 id=(TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't rely on view id to access data.

you should have a separate model (let's say an ArrayList) containing the data shown in the listview. when the user select an item you grab the position of the item listed and pick the corresponding item in the array where you could find all information